# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

I have created a dll with controls. when i browse the dll it adds the controls to the toolbox successfully. the problem is that when i run the application, i get the following error :
`An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in xxx.dll`

the method where the debugger goes highlight the error is in the function below:

```
public ItemType this[int i]
{
    get
{
    return (ItemType)this[i];
}
set
{
    this[i] = value;
}
}
```

as i know this error occurs because of recursive call, how can i rewrite the above or modify it to overcome this issue. Please any code help as soon as possible

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should use an internal list in your Class.

```
    private IList<ItemType> _list = new List<ItemType>();
    public ItemType this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            return _list[i];
        }
        set
        {
            _list[i] = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: now i get the Object reference not set to an instance of an object in  return _list[i];

Comment: Just initialize the list first. Of course in the sample code _list is always null.

Comment: actually the itemtype was BaseItemCollection<OwnerType, ItemType>._knownTypes = new Type[] { typeof(ItemType) }; then how should i change the recursive function

Answer (score 0):

**I solved the problem, as follows:**

```
public ItemType this[int i] 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return (ItemType)((IList)this)[i]; 
    } 
    set 
    { 
        this[i] = value; 
    } 
}
```